# How to use the duplicated cookie in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, https, jmeter, request

A request

Response cookie:
content-version:12345678, content-version:98654321

B request

Request Cookie:
content-version:${COOKIE_content-version}

The situation is that I am now using Jmeter to perform the stress test. There are two HTTP requests. In A request, there are two response cookies having the same name but different values. Now, I want to use the second value which is 98654321 in B request. However, if I use ${COOKIE_content-version}, it will use the first value which is 12345678. May I ask how can I take the second value?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality if multiple cookies have the same name it's the [browser who decides which one is to send back](https://www.sitepoint.com/3-things-about-cookies-you-may-not-know/).

If you absolutely need to send the "second" cookie - don't rely on the HTTP Cookie Manager, just extract the "second" cookie from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) configured like:

[image]

refer the extracted value as `${cookie}` where required

Comment: thanks for answering